# Is there any way to set up TeamCity agents to run on a round robin schedule?

Tags: build, teamcity

We are building several project with TeamCity.  In addition to an agent on the main server which runs on Linux, we also have three additional agents that run on separate boxes.  One on Linux, one on Mac and one on Windows.

If all agents are idle, the first available agent, as they are listed, is chosen for the build.  This means that if the load on TeamCity is small, the same agent is always used.  We have had situations where a project had been built successfully by the same Linux agent for more than 50 builds, then when it finally had a run on the Windows agent, a test failed, due to code that was committed fairly early in the run of the 50 builds.

Since many of our tests may be affected by the environment, we are looking for ways to spread the builds on the agents, automatically.  Is there any way of setting up a round robin agent selection policy?  Or any other way to spread the builds on the agents?

Comment: Just a correction to a statement above:  Support from JetBrains states that TeamCity chooses the agent that will run the build fastest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question, at least for TeamCity 8 and earlier, is NO.

See JetBrains own TeamCity Developer forum: https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5533629

Answer (score 2):

You can have a schedule trigger that runs a build on all agents.
Or configure a build for each platform (linux,windows, mac, ...) that will run on a specific agent, selected with some specific requirements.

Comment: Yes. It looks like that will be our solution. JetBrains have confirmed to me, that there is no option for a round robin agent selection.